# Custom autocompleter and periods (.)

Tags: ace-editor

I can't seem to make *getCompletions* function to trigger in my custom completer when using custom prefix extraction regex  *identifierRegexps*

Basically I am trying to create an autocompleter which will trigger on periods (.) preceded by letters. E.g. In "foo." when the period is typed I would like to present my custom suggestions.

```js
var lang = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
editor.setOptions({
  enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  enableSnippets: true,
  enableLiveAutocompletion: true
});

var compl = {
  identifierRegexps: [/[a-zA-Z_0-9\.\$\-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/],
  getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    alert(prefix);

    callback(null, []);
    return;
  }
}
lang.addCompleter(compl);
```

With the above snippet, suggestions popup appears when typing a dot but *getCompletions* doesn't trigger. However, it does trigger on any other character.

**UPDATE:**

Removing default completers prior to adding the custom one with

```
lang.setCompleters();
```

makes the *getCompletion* function to trigger. However *prefix* argument is empty in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to solve it by modifying the ID_REGEX var in language_tools.js.

Comment: This is not a fine solution, because we can't simply customize prefix for different completers.

Comment: This is not necessary anymore, there was a bug in Ace which is fixed.  For those using Brace, the current version uses an Ace version that has this fix so you should also have no problem using `identifierRegexps`.  But you have to keep in mind that Ace starts matching at the end of the input.  E.g. if input ends with `.test` it will try to match `t`, then `st`, then `est`, then `test` and then`.test`.  It stops as soon as it fails to match and then uses the last match as prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the `language_tools.js` file is not a good solution, you can adjust the regex pattern by calling the method `getCompletionRegex`:

```
editor.getCompletionRegex = () => /[a-zA-Z_0-9.\$\-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/;
```

Comment: do you mean `\.` instead of `.`?

Comment: @BernardoRamos I know this is late, but since it's in square brackets, the `\` is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

In the ext-language-tools.js file,

Replace 
`var ID_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z_0-9\$\-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/;`

to

```
var ID_REGEX = /[a-zA-Z_0-9\.\$\-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/;
```

With the above ID_REGEX the autocomplete will now trigger on periods (.)