# Ace editor autocomplete identifierRegexps doesn't work in live-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, regex, ace-editor

I am using custom completer in the ace editor and hope it can detect string ends with a dot, eg: 'class.' Actually, there are two situations that confused me:

the custom completer:

```
  var customCompleter = {
      // custom prefix to match dot
      identifierRegexps: [/[a-zA-Z_0-9\.\-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/],
      getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
          console.log("prefix",prefix);
          if (prefix.length === 0) { callback(null, []); return }
          let matches = produceMatch;
          callback(null, matches);
       }
    };
    // add completer
    langTools.addCompleter(customCompleter);
    editor.setOptions({enableLiveAutocompletion: 'customCompleter'});
```

1. I set: identifierRegexps: [/[a-zA-Z]+.?$/], and this regex is tested well on several online regex webs. I keep print the prefix, but it cannot detect any dot just pure string. Like its default ID_regex(in ex-language_tool), it treats dot as an end of the string.
2. Refer to situation1 I simple modified identifierRegexps from ID_regex: identifierRegexps: [/[a-zA-Z_0-9.-\u00A2-\uFFFF]/]. Now it can detect string with dot, but only for more than one dot. For example:
   **input: `c` - prefix: `c`;

   input: `c.` - no prefix;

   input: `c..` - prefix: `c..`;

   input: `.` - prefix: `.`;

   input: `..` - prefix: `..`;**
   But the wired thing is, when I change completer to basic mode, it just goes well and give right prefix string, but to meet the requirement the completer needs to be live.

I think it might be caused by the difference of how it cut off a regex match in live mode. I've read the source code but still have no clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920998/custom-autocompleter-and-periods