# Custom autocomplete in ace-editor does not work after "."

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to use autocomplete in the ace editor. After the user types `foo.` I want to suggest `foo.bar`.

Actually I used the following code:

```
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");

var staticWordCompleter = {
    identifierRegexps: [/[\.]/],
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        console.log(prefix);
        if (prefix == "foo.") {
            var wordList = ["baar", "bar", "baz"];
            callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
                return {
                    caption: word,
                    value: word,
                    meta: "static"
                };
        }
        }));

    }
}

langTools.setCompleters([staticWordCompleter])
```

If I remove `identifierRegexps` and the `if` clause, the autocomplete works but not after ".".

I also read this solution but it does not work anymore: [Custom autocompleter and periods (.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920998/custom-autocompleter-and-periods)

Comment: maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57141935/4626775

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the "." and then build your wordList. You can make your wordList global and use in the **getCompletions** or once you bind the "." use this code to get the before item ie foo, and then insert the value into the editor.

```
    self.editor.commands.addCommand({
        name: "dotCommand1",
        bindKey: { win: ".", mac: "." },
        exec: function () {
            var pos = editor.selection.getCursor();
            var session = editor.session;

            var curLine = (session.getDocument().getLine(pos.row)).trim();
            var curTokens = curLine.slice(0, pos.column).split(/\s+/);
            var curCmd = curTokens[0];
            if (!curCmd) return;
            var lastToken = curTokens[curTokens.length - 1];

            editor.insert(".");                

            if (lastToken === "foo") {
                // Add your words to the list or then insert into the editor using editor.insert()
            }
        }
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I'm too stupid to put your example into practice. Could you take a look at the example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjXmNw

Comment: Hey, sorry I made a small change to the code here. And can you make your wordList as a global array and update the workList once the lastToken matches "foo". And you can make a common function for the autocomplete and call that function once the last token matches

Comment: It would be great if you could put this into a working example @Harshapps - from this "accepted" answer it's not clear what the full solution as the original poster's code doesn't apply. You are missing the glue :)