# Ace editor add custom JS API

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is there a way to add custom JS API to the ace autocomplete feature?

Let's say I have the following object:

```
const myApi = {
  methodOne() {}
  methodTwo() {}
}
```

When the user is typing `myApi.` I need to show  `methodOne` and `methodTwo` as suggestions.

I tried to play with the completion API, but I didn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to just list the names of the methods here?

Comment: Yes, methods, properties, anything I would like to add.

Comment: You only want to show the string names right of the methods and properties?

Comment: yes for the autocomplete

Comment: Did you try using the autocomplete feature? I guess you would have to store the names of constants and its methods in a keylist array. As the Ace autocomplete would show an autocompletion list from the keylist array. Are you fine with storing all the keywords in the array

Comment: But I need the autocompletion when the use type "dot"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50482228/3596851 Can you try this answer once?